# Are monads current "state of the art" to do IO in pure languages?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am wondering whether there are any new approaches considered as viable (better) alternative to Haskell's Monad IO that has been around for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main alternatives are effect systems. See http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~benl/papers/thesis/lippmeier-impure-world.pdf for an example. There are many of them, so your question cannot be sensibly answered. See also [What is a type and effect system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196465/805266)

Comment: Classifying effects by the monads that describe them could be considered an effect system, in which case Haskell could be considered to have a somewhat crude effect system. However, the alternative to monadic encapsulation of effects seems to be substructural typing of effectful computations (via linear, affine, uniqueness etc. types) along with other notions like regions or capabilities. Although these other systems allow finer-grained control of effects, they tend to introduce their own set of complications, so it's difficult to say if they will prove more useful in practice than monads.

Comment: More details on the connection to effects can be found in [The marriage of effects and monads](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/effectstocl/effectstocl.pdf) by Philip Wadler and Peter Thiemann.

Answer (score 1):

> Is monadic I/O currently the "state of the art" in pure languages?

By itself? No - abstracting away I/O behind a monadic interface has been happening for close to 30 years.

What is new are abstractions over monadic I/O such as *iteratees*; Owen Stpehens provides more details in his overview [Approaches to Functional I/O](https://www.owenstephens.co.uk/assets/static/research/masters_report.pdf). He summarises the current situation:

> I/O is not a particularly active area of research, but
> new approaches are still being discovered [...]

[Ben Lynn](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/haskell/io.html) makes a similar observation:

> And now that we can write mostly pure code with occasional impure
> wrappers, researchers have mostly stopped seeking superior
> alternatives.

[Conal Elliott](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional) describes it quite memorably:

> With the invention and acceptance of monadic imperative programming, it's
> like the Haskell community wandered into an opium den and are still
> lying there in a fog.
>
> Okay, I may be exaggerating a bit. Some are in rehab, and some
> "didn't inhale".

It was the ugliness of dialogues that helped to propel the monadic interface to such prominence - could monadic I/O ever be considered ugly enough to give rise to an all-new replacement?

Only time will tell...